# SQL - Compare 2 tables then add unique items to 3rd table

Tags: sql

Title kind of says it all.

I have 2 tables Both with matching data

```
Table Name: Customers
_____________________________
ID   | CompanyName
--------------
1    | Joes
2    | Kennys
3    | Kellys
4    | Ricks
5    | Johns


Table Name: OldCustomers
_____________________________
ID   | CompanyName
--------------
1    | Joes
2    | Kennys
3    | Kellys
4    | Ricks
```

I want to do a comparison between the two tables. Then take the Row that doesn't exist in Table 2, and add it to a table i've created called "NewCustomers"

Comment: Please state what database you are using Oracle, SQL Server, MySQL ...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the following:

```
insert into NewCustomers(id, companyname)
select c.id
  , c.companyname
from Customers c 
left join OldCustomers oc
  on c.companyname = oc.companyname
where oc.id is null;

select *
from NewCustomers
```

See [SQL Fiddle with Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/469c6/1)

This query will find all records where the company name is missing from the OldCustomers table.  If you want to join on both id and company name you would just add `and c.id = oc.id` to the `left join`. It will give you the same results.